# My service will not die (even though my code says it is dead)

Tags: android, service

SO ive been using the following tutorial to get a gps service going:

http://www.marioalmeida.eu/2014/02/21/how-to-do-android-ipc-using-messenger-to-a-remote-service/

I got it working and my GPS works fine and its all good. My problem is that I cant kill the service. I thought calling unbind on it would kill it but it didnt. I am using a wakelock to keep the service awake so it can record the GPS co-ordinates (its a location tracker). Then after I unbind I release the wakelock. I alos have a piece of code that checks if the service is running. Before I call unbind (this is where I release the wakelock too) it is but after I call unbind it is not.

The problem is in my service I have toast messages popping up so I know where the code is. Even after I kill the service these toast messages are still popping up.

Can anyone tell me how my service could still be running after I have unbound and checked that the service is not running? Im completely stumped

Comment: Why are you using a service in the first place? If it is only around while you are bound to it, and you should only be bound to it while you are in the foreground, what's the point of having a service?

Comment: I use a service so when the phone locks the location is still being recorded

Answer (score 2):

Unbinding a service does not stop a service. You can stop your service by simply calling stop service:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context,MyService.class)
stopService(i);
```

or you can use `stopSelf()` inside your service class.

Comment: "unbinding a service does not stop a service" -- it does if there are no other outstanding bindings and nobody called `startService()`.

Comment: I tried stopSelf earlier and now I tried the above but neither work. stopService returns true when i step through the code so it seems to think it is stopping it but i keep getting the toast messages. (Just so ye know, the toast messages come from the onLocationChanged method of the service, which implements LocationListener).

Comment: @discodowney remove your location listener and disconnect on onDestroy (Assuming you are using the Fused Location Provider)